# over write the parent style

Tags: html, css

I have multiple `h1` tags. Since I have written style for parent `h1`, same style is applying to the another `h1` which has its own parent.

This is the new parent div inside the main parent. I need to change the style of this h1.

```
<div class="company_details">
                <h1>New H1 title here</h1>
                <a href="#">www.julysystems.com</a>
            </div>
```

And this is the css written for he above h1 and it is not applying

```
<!--Company Details-->
#accordion div > div.company_details h1{
    font-size:50px !important;
}
```

Here is the **[CODE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/auTdQ/2/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a HTML comment in the middle of the style sheet:

```
<!--Company Details-->
```

Remove that, and it works. You don't even need the `!important`.

To put a comment in CSS, you use `/*` and `*/`:

```
/* Company Details */
```

Comment: silly silly silly mistake of mine.... No idea when I added html comment there.. Thank you :) working now